# Run your request and receive new data Json

Tags: java, android

I have a problem. When I do a query in the stream, I have downloaded the data from the URL, everything works. But when I call AsynsTask example by pressing doInBackground() method that returns the same data, but they are updated on the URL. And they will not be updated as long as the program is restarted.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("data.php?"+new Random().nextInt(200));

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            jSON_R = buffer.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jSON_R;
    }
```

> All code

```
public class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    int intRow = 0;
    String jSON_R = "";

    private List<User> movieList;


    Activity act;

    ListView list;
    LAdapter adapter;

    boolean Unique = true;

    public ParseTask (Activity act){
        this.act = act;
    }


    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL("data.php?"+new Random().nextInt(200));

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                jSON_R = buffer.toString();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jSON_R;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        list = (ListView) act.findViewById(R.id.listVew);

        Button b = (Button) act.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //To do
            }
        });


        movieList = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new LAdapter(act, movieList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        try {
            JSONObject dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray jsa = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsa.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject data1 = chat.getJSONObject(i);
                String mes = data1.getString("mes1");
                String mes2 = data1.getString("mes2");
                String mes3 = data1.getString("mes3");

                User m = new User(mes, mes2, mes3);

                movieList.add(0, m);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            intRow = jsa.length();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if (firstVisibleItem > 1){
                    Unique = false;
                }else{
                    Unique = true;
                }

            }
        });

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true){
                        sleep(5000);
                        if (Unique){
                            act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Update();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    private void Update(){

            try {
            JSONObject dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray jsa = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsa.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject data1 = chat.getJSONObject(i);
                String mes = data1.getString("mes1");
                String mes2 = data1.getString("mes2");
                String mes3 = data1.getString("mes3");

                User m = new User(mes, mes2, mes3);

                movieList.add(0, m);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            intRow = jsa.length();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

}
```

> Calling the object in such a way

```
new ParseTask(getActivity()).execute();
```

Comment: Show us also the code that works please.

Comment: Added code completely.

Comment: "pressing doInBackground() method" what does that mean? from your code, it looks like you expect the `Update` method to update things, but there is no indication that the data it is using changes.

Comment: But how can that be. Called method. It creates new objects. The novel compound. That means that the new data should be returned.

Comment: @NickNick Use wireshark to capture and inspect the network traffic your app sends to your server and the response it returns. Check that the server is actually returning different data to you. I think that the URL you use for your request is incorrect and that the server is always returning the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Close the connection.

I mean use (better) `reader.close()` or `inputStream.close()`

Or try jsoup library https://jsoup.org/

Comment: I've already done that. Does not help. Before we used to write here all the possible options.

Comment: @NickNick ,try jsoup. It works like charm! Url in the answer